# navigator.onLine dose not work on windows

Tags: javascript, navigator

I'm sorry. I do not speak English well.

"navigator.onLine" API does not work properly in Windows. 
Even if the network is disconnected, only true is returned.
The same thing happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.
However, it works fine on mac.

```
// I disconnected my computer from the network and ran the code below from the console.

console.log('network status', navigator.onLine); 
// => true
```

What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [what](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)